# Dynamics CRM - SQL query to get entity that lookup relates to

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

Within the CRM database, where can I find the name of the entity that a lookup field relates to?

For example, I have an `Account` entity  which contains two lookup fields;

- *Account Contact*, which points to the `Contact` entity
- *Leased Equipment*, which points to the  `Equipment` entity

How can I get the name of the entity that each of the fields relates to?

I expected to see this in the `MetadataSchema.AttributeLookupValue` table, but this doesn't seem to be the right place.

Ideally, I'd like to write a query for this information. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    AttributeName,
    AttributeTypeName,
    ReferencedEntityName
FROM 
    unknown.TableName

WHERE
    AttributeName IN ('new_AccountContact', 'new_LeasedEquipment')

-- Results:
-- AttributeName        | AttributeTypeName | ReferencedEntityName
-- new_AccountContact   | lookup            | Contact
-- new_LeasedEquipment  | lookup            | Equipment
```

Any help trying to achieve this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below returns the primary entity, lookup field name, and the target entity type of the lookup field.

```
    SELECT e.Name 'primary entity' , a.LogicalName 'lookup field in primary entity' , a.ReferencedEntityObjectTypeCode , e2.LogicalName as 'target entity of the lookup field'
    FROM MetadataSchema.Attribute a inner join MetadataSchema.Entity e on a.EntityId = e.EntityId
                                    inner join MetadataSchema.Entity e2 on a.ReferencedEntityObjectTypeCode=e2.ObjectTypeCode
    WHERE  ReferencedEntityObjectTypeCode <>0
    AND e.name='account'
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, however this doesn't give the the name of the entity that the lookup relates to. Instead, this gives me the Name of the Contact instance or the Name of the Leased Equipment. For example, if my Contact was called *John Smith*, this query returns *John Smith*, instead of returning Contacts (the name of the entity that the lookup field relates to).